Is Minkowski space contractible?
I would like to apply the Poincaré lemma to Minkowski space. For this I need that the space is contractible. How could I prove this?

From Wikipedia: "For an overview, Minkowski space is a 4-dimensional real vector space [...]." Finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ (endowed with the product topology) are obviously contractible via $(x, t) \mapsto (1 - t) x$.

Don't get fooled by the Minkowski space tag. Minkowski space ist just $\mathbb{R}^4$ with a certain choice of metric. This metric, however, is not important for the Poincare lemma, since it only requires a notion of differential calculus and no metric.
Now, you only need to show that $\mathbb{R}^4$ is contractible. This is a vector space. Can you do that? :-)

Yes, because it is an euclidean space!

Yes exactly. Even though I think the term "Euclidean space" should be used with care, since it sort of implies that we choose the metric tensor $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ instead of the Minkowski space-time metric tensor.

That's another reason that I prefer the term "Cartesian space" for $\mathbb R^n$. Euclidean space is then $\mathbb R^4$ with (as you say) a certain choice of metric. But I'm not going to win this battle...

To be honest, I think being sloppy with terms/notation is one of the biggest entry-level barriers for differential geometry learners.

The contractibility of a space depends only on its topology. The underlying topology on Minkowski space is the usual 'Euclidean' topology on $\mathbb{R}^4$, and this topological space is contractible of course.
Indeed, usually in relativity theory (e.g., in general relativity), the smooth manifold structure (and hence, the topology) is given before the (pseudo-Riemannian) metric. In particular, in the case of Minkowski space, the smooth manifold structure (and hence, the topology) is usually implicitly taken as the usual one on $\mathbb{R}^4$.
Remark: There are so-called 'exotic smooth manifold structures' on $\mathbb{R}^4$, and their use have been investigated in relativity theory, e.g., in this paper. However, these smooth structures all have the same underlying topology, hence are still contractible.
